# AWK - Parsing SQL output

Tags: sql, bash, awk

I have a SQL output something like below from the output of a custom tool. Would appreciate any help in finding what I am doing incorrectly.

```
column1                  | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |     column7     | column8 | column9 |        column10            |          column11          
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------
 cec75                   | 1234     | 007    |         |    2810 |         | SOME_TEXT       |         |         | 2020-12-07 20:28:46.865+00 | 2020-12-08 06:40:10.231635+00
(1 row)
```

I am trying to pipe this output the columns I need in my case **column1**, **column2**, and **column7**. I have tried piping out like this but it just prints **column1**

`tool check | awk '{print $1, $2}'`

```
column1 |
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+------------------------------- 
cec75 |
(1 row)
```

It would be nice to have something like this.

```
ce7c5,1234,SOME_TEXT
```

My file contents

```
                  column1                  | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |     column7     | column8 | column9 |        column10         |          column11          
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------
 6601c | 2396     | 123         |             |               9350 |                       | SOME_TEXT |               |                | 2020-12-07 22:49:01.023+00 | 2020-12-08 07:22:37.419669+00
(1 row)


                  column1                  | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |     column7     | column8 | column9 |        column10         |          column11          
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------
 cec75 | 1567     | 007        |             |               2810 |                       | SOME_TEXT |               |                | 2020-12-07 20:28:46.865+00 | 2020-12-08 07:28:10.319888+00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Your newly edited file is very much different from initial shown samples, please try to post samples(near to your Input_file) on very first place itslef.

Comment: What is `My file contents` - sample input, expected output, actual output or something else? If it's sample input where is the expected output and vice-versa? Do your table always have exactly 1 row of data or could they have 2 or more (and if so include that in your example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description:**

Command line switches...

- The delimiter is `|` surrounded by spaces.  (Note that we need to use a couple of `\`'s to escape `|` if we feed the regex for the delimiter in from the command line.)
- In addition to input delimiter (input field separator) the output delimiter (output field separator) can also be set using a command line switch.

The **awk** script...

- If a header is encountered or a `(` is seen on a line, it's not a valid line; so, just ignore it.
- If the line now has any alphanumeric characters, it's now a valid line to operate on; so, and we strip the leading spaces off the line, and then print the columns we want.

```
tool check | awk -F' *\\| *' -v OFS=, '/column|\(/ { next } /[[:alnum:]]/ { sub(/^ +/, ""); print $1, $2, $7 }'
```

Examining the data more closely... It looks as though the date-stamp (which always has a `:` in it) might be present on all valid records... If so, the script can be reduced to something much more simple.

```
tool check | awk -F' *\\| *' -v OFS=, '$10 ~ /:/ { sub(/^ +/, ""); print $1, $2, $7 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set correct `FS` and somehow filters out undesired (junk) lines. I would do it following way. Let `file.txt` content be:

```
column1                  | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 |     column7     | column8 | column9 |        column10            |          column11          
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------
 cec75                   | 1234     | 007    |         |    2810 |         | SOME_TEXT       |         |         | 2020-12-07 20:28:46.865+00 | 2020-12-08 06:40:10.231635+00
(1 row)
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]+\\|[[:space:]]+";OFS=","}(NR>=2 && NF>=2){print $1,$2,$7}' file.txt
```

output:

```
cec75,1234,2020-12-07 20:28:46.865+00
```

Explanation: I set field separator (`FS`) to one or more `:space:` literal `|` one or more `:space:` where `:space:` means any whitespace. Depending on your data you might elect to use zero or more rather than one or more - to do so replace `+` with `*`. For every line which is not first one (this filter out header) and has at least 2 fields (this filter out line with `-` and `+` and `(1 row)`) I print content of 1st column followed by `,` followed by content of 2nd column followed by `,` followed by content of 7th column.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP added edited set of samples, so adding this solution now. This considers that you want to print lines after lines which starts from `---`.

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' '/^---/{found=1;next} found{print $1,$2,$7;found=""}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
your_command | 
awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*' '/^---/{found=1;next} found{print $1,$2,$7;found=""}'
```

Comment: added the line and I do not get any output back ` tool check | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*"} FNR==3{print $1,$7}'  `

Comment: @AjaySridhara, these worked for me with shown samples. Is your actual file same as shown samples?

Comment: @RavindraSingh13 - I tried all three and it just outputs the header `column1 column7`

Comment: @AjaySridhara,  could you please run once `your_command | awk '{print FNR}'` want to check is your output coming into a single line or in multiple lines? Let me know

Comment: @RavindraSingh13 - This is what I get. `tool check | awk '{print FNR}'                       
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28 `

Comment: @AjaySridhara, `tool check | awk '{print FNR},$0}'` in this one which line your output comes? Please let me know.

Comment: @AjaySridhara, Kindly check my EDIT solution once and let me know if this helps you?